# Deleting every item in a list corresponding to match in other list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am showing two cases of many such cases to explain the problem. Each case
has two lists. First list i.e. `nu` contains elements ID , which has to be matched with first element of every tuple in second list i.e. `nu_ew`.
If the match is found, I want to delete every occurrence of tuple with same ID from the second list i.e. `nu_ew`.

Issue is that I am successfully able to **delete** all desired element (tuple) from Case-2, but last occurrence of element (tuple) i.e. `('Na23', 0.0078838)` corresponding to last ID in `nu` remains undeleted in Case-1.

I am looking for any way out to get desired result. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Case-1:

`nu=['F19', 'U234', 'U235', 'U238', 'Cl35', 'Cl37', 'Na23']`

```
nu_ew = [('Mg24', 0.070385),    ('Mg25', 0.0092824), 
         ('Mg26', 0.0106276),   ('F19', 0.42348), 
         ('U234', 1.083506277), ('U235', 0.0014516), 
         ('U238', 0.202605),    ('Cl35', 0.0454252), 
         ('Cl37', 0.0153641),   ('Na23', 0.047303), 
         ('F19', 0.0521210),    ('U234', 3.61168759), 
         ('U235', 0.000483890), ('U238', 0.067535), 
         ('F19', 0.0217170),    ('Na23', 0.0078838), 
         ('Cl35', 0.0181700),   ('Cl37', 0.0061456)]
```

Case-2:

`nu=['F19', 'U234', 'U235', 'U238']`

```
nu_ew = [('Mg24', 0.068893),   ('Mg25', 0.009085), 
         ('Mg26', 0.0104025),   ('F19', 0.414511), 
         ('U234', 1.060551431), ('U235', 0.0014209), 
         ('U238', 0.198313),    ('Cl35', 0.0444628), 
         ('Cl37', 0.0150386),   ('Na23', 0.046301), 
         ('F19', 0.0510167),    ('U234', 5.65627430), 
         ('U235', 0.00075782),  ('U238', 0.105767), 
         ('F19', 0.034011)]
```

I tried doing:

```
for n in nu:
    for ind, id_wf in enumerate(nu_ew):
        if n == id_wf[0]:
            del nu_ew[ind]`

print(nu_ew)`
```

Comment: Is you code running?

Comment: Does `('Cl35', 0.0181700)` get deleted in case 1?

Comment: @ Yugandhar Chaudhari : Yes, posted code is running.

Comment: @ Mad Physicist : Yes, ('Cl35', 0.0181700) gets deleted.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use list comprehension here:
something like

```
result = [t for t in nu_ew if t[0] not in nu]
```

For larger lists

```
nu_as_set = set(nu)
result = [t for t in nu_ew if t[0] not in nu_as_set]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Solution is brief and elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Two points to address.

1. Don't delete/add an element to a list while iterating over it. Instead, make a new list containing the result. This can be done by a for loop, or by list comprehension.
2. You don't have to iterate over `nu`, just use `in`. If `nu` is going to be larger, consider using a set, because it takes less time with `in` operator.

So, either one of the following will work for your second code.

1. Use `for` loop.

```py
result = []
for id_wf in nu_ew:
    if id_wf[0] in nu:
        result.append(id_wf)
nu_ew = result
print(nu_ew)
```

2. Use list comprehension.

```py
nu_ew = [id_wf in nu_ew if id_wf[0] in nu]
```

---

Making a set out of `nu` is simple, just add

```py
nu = set(nu)
```

or

```py
nu_set = set(nu)
```

(If you want to keep the original list)

beforehand.